# mysql query group by same repeat datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem making a query. I have a table with records where some repeat the datetime. I have to bring the last of each from where the datetime repeats. Example:

| id | value | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-03 08:30:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-03 08:30:00 |
| 3 | 3 | **2021-01-03 08:30:00** |
| 4 | 0 | **2021-01-03 08:30:10** |
| 5 | 4 | 2021-01-03 08:30:20 |
| 6 | 8 | 2021-01-03 08:30:20 |
| 7 | 0 | **2021-01-03 08:30:20** |

it should return the id 3,4 and 7

can u help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of "repeat"?  It is not obvious.

Comment: What have you tried, post your queries, and table structure

Comment: Select maximal `id` for each `datetime` in subquery, use this data for rows filtering.

Comment: @CBroe ??? source data contains ids from 1 to 7. OP needs to select *id 3,4 and 7* (he marks them bold) - your words contradict this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `lead()` for this.  Based on your *question*, it would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lead(datetime) over (order by id) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where next_datetime is null or next_datetime <> datetime;
```

Based on your sample data, there is some sort of unspecified threshold.  So, something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lead(datetime) over (order by id) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where next_datetime is null or
      next_datetime < datetime + interval 11 second;
```

Note:  This assumes that the `datetime` values increase along with the `id`, which is a reasonable assumption given the data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last id for each of the same datetime:

```
SELECT timestamp, max(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY timestamp;
```

To get the complete row for each of the same datetime:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  timestamp,
  FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER BY id DESC),
  FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER BY id DESC)
FROM table;
```